# Правильно ли словосочетание «вакансия на»?

Tags: выбор-слов

Прочитал комментарий [под записью](https://vk.com/liveexp?w=wall-32295218_328909). Автор говорит, что предлог *на* здесь лишний. Контекст: *вакансия на дизайнера*. И действительно, мне тоже это режет слух, а вот с грамматической стороны я не могу доказать, почему этот вариант ошибочный. Вакансия — это свободная должность. Получается, мы ищем человека на должность. И как всё-таки быть? Прошу рассудить.

Comment: Ссылка в вашем вопросе требует подписку на VK.  Пожалуйста, не используйте ссылок, которые требуют подписок.

Comment: Подписку? Какую подписку? Вы о чём?

Comment: Я о Вашей ссылке, обозначенной у Вас словами "под записью" - https://vk.com/feed?w=wall-32295218_328909.  Попытка открыть страницу по этой ссылке требует регистрации.

Comment: Вот теперь всё понятно. Я исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вакансия, как вы отметили, "свободная должность". Ищем на должность кого? , а не: должность на. Правильно: занимать должность кого-то, а не на что. Поэтому предлог ***на*** здесь ошибочен.